# How to toggle comment COBOL style in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: comments, sublimetext2, cobol

I've been using sublime text 2 for writing COBOL codes. However, it's default toggle comment/toggle comment block isn't really usefull for me. When i'm using it, it turns out like this:

```
*> 000100 ID DIVISION.                                                     00010002
```

I need the asterisk to be exactly at column 7 which is how mainframe COBOL comments really work.

```
000100*ID DIVISION.                                                     00010002
```

Im only using record/playback macro but if this can be done it would be much easier.

How can I edit Sublime text's way to toggle comment?

Comment: Why don't you Record putting * in column seven?

Comment: FWIW the Zeus editor (which runs on Windows and also on Linux using Wine) has a add/remove comment macro (found on the Macros menu) that will add/remove the COBOL '*' at the column 7 location.

Comment: If you update your plugin this is now fixed.. :-)